# Facebook Ads API via Javascript SDK - How to get ad accounts &campaigns for business manager account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have an Angular 5 app where I need to grab some data from my ad accounts via a Business Manager account that I have been made an admin of. I'm having trouble figuring out which API documentation I need to follow and which endpoints to call.

I'm just trying to figure out how to get data from the Graph API Explorer that Facebook provides and when I try something like this:

`/v2.12/<business-account-id>/adaccounts` I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) adaccounts field is deprecated for versions v2.11 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "AV2JHORP+bN"
  }
}
```

I have all the correct permissions set with my access token, though I'm not sure what to call to get that data. There are a lot of different API docs and I'm not sure which ones to follow.

Has anyone run into this as well?

Comment: Hi @Stevie, did you get any response or found any solution. I am hitting the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Stevie, found that this endpoint /v2.11/BUSINESS_ID/owned_ad_accounts seems to work for me. But not sure, if I get all accounts. Found it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote [a blog post](https://washamdev.com/facebook-sdk-javascript-tutorial-graph-api-facebook-login/) explaining in-depth how to do this, and here is a brief overview:

### Ad Accounts Owned by Your Business

To get the list of ad accounts that your Business account owns, you can make a call to the following URL:

```
/<API_VERSION>/<BUSINESS_ID>/owned_ad_accounts
```

Read more at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/assets

### Ad Accounts Owned by Your Clients

You can pull all ad accounts owned by other Business accounts by using the [client_ad_accounts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/client_ad_accounts/) edge:

```
/<API_VERSION>/<BUSINESS_ID>/client_ad_accounts?fields=id,name,business
```

Requesting the `business` field will give you information about the Business that is sharing the ad account to you.

(Thanks to user skinnyas123 for reminding me about the new edge to get clients' ad accounts! I began using it awhile back and forgot to update this answer.)

Comment: Since I have stumbled upon the same question, I have figured out that you can access them Ad Accounts Shared to Your Business thru /<API_VERSION>/<BUSINESS_ID>/client_ad_accounts. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business